# IIS is forcing me to login in order to load my CSS and Javascript files when using Windows Authentication on a subdirectory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have an asp.net MVC application that has one section `/admin` locked down via windows authentication. I have achieved this by doing the following.

**Web.Config**

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

**AdminController**

```
[Authorize]
public class ContactController : Controller
{
   ....
}
```

This works as it should. When I try to access the `/admin` URI it prompts me for a windows login.

***However***, in my `/Views/Admin/Index.aspx` view, I am linking to two files:

```
<script src="/media/js/site.js"></script>
<style href="/media/css/styles.css" ... />
```

For some reason IIS is prompting me for a windows login for each of these files too.

- If I hit cancel (after the first
  login), then the page loads, but
  without any CSS or Javascript.
- If I
  remove those tags from my view, then
  I am only prompted to login one time
  and it "works".

So why is windows prompting me to authenticate for the CSS & JS files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### SOLVED

As with most problems like this, turns out it was a **permissions error**.

I gave "Read" access on the media folder to the windows user that I was logging in with and ***bam*** it all works dandy now.

Answer (score 4):

I know you've already closed your answer but I'll give you my 2/cents.
A better approach will be to authorize everyone to the media folder in the web.config:

```
  <location path="media" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Also, specifying security in the `web.config` for other resources.